# How do I disable SQLAlchemy query caching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, caching, sqlalchemy

I am writing a script to test the performance of PostgreSQL in Python using SQLAlchemy. The point of testing is that I have a loop, in each iteration of the loop certain queries with a fixed amount of data are called and I measure the execution time of the queries, then in the next iteration the amount of data increases. For example, I want to test for [1000, 2000, 3000] lines. On the first iteration everything is fine, but then sqlalchemy saves the received data in the cache, and on the next iteration it queries only 1000 rows from the database and takes 1000 rows from the cache, and etc.How do I disable it?

I tried a lot of methods: adding session.expires_all(), different execution_options, creating new session with sessionmaker for every query function, use different isolation lvls, but sqlalchemy still caching data.

```
# example of query function
@get_exec_time
def select_from_data(session_obj, field_name, field_value, mode="json"):

    tgt_table = None

    if mode not in ("json", "jsonb"):
        raise TypeError("Значение mode должно быть равно json/jsonb")

    if mode == "json":
        tgt_table = JsonMedicalData
        filter_expr = tgt_table.json_data.op("->>")(field_name).cast(Integer) == field_value

    elif mode == "jsonb":
        tgt_table = JsonbMedicalData
        filter_expr = tgt_table.jsonb_data.op("@>")({field_name: field_value})

    with session_obj.begin() as session:
        session.expire_all()
        result = session.query(tgt_table).filter(filter_expr).all()
```

Test pipeline

```
row_numbers = [100000, 150000, 200000, 250000]

results_dict = {}

# generate rows
json_rows_max, jsonb_rows_max = data_generator(row_numbers[-1], mode="json"), data_generator(row_numbers[-1], mode="jsonb")

for rows in row_numbers:
    json_rows, jsonb_rows = json_rows_max[:rows], jsonb_rows_max[:rows]

    # json insert files
    json_insert_time = insert_test(json_rows, Session)
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="insert", row_number=rows, mode="json", exec_time=json_insert_time)

    # select where json
    select_where_time = select_from_data(Session, field_name="select_test", field_value=5, mode="json")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="select", row_number=rows, mode="json", exec_time=select_where_time)

    # summarize json data
    summarize_data_time = summarize_data_field(Session, field_name="зарегистрировано всего", mode="json")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="summarize", row_number=rows, mode="json", exec_time=summarize_data_time)

    # delete json data
    json_delete_time = delete_test(JsonMedicalData, Session)
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="delete", row_number=rows, mode="json", exec_time=json_delete_time)

    # jsonb insert files
    jsonb_insert_time = insert_test(jsonb_rows, Session)
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="insert", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb", exec_time=jsonb_insert_time)

    # select where jsonb
    select_where_time = select_from_data(Session, field_name="select_test", field_value=5, mode="jsonb")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="select", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb", exec_time=select_where_time)

    # summarize jsonb data
    summarize_data_time = summarize_data_field(Session, field_name="зарегистрировано всего", mode="jsonb")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="summarize", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb", exec_time=summarize_data_time)

    # create gin index on jsonb data
    gin_index_create_time = gin_index_create(Session, "gin_index")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="gin_create", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb_gin", exec_time=gin_index_create_time)

    # select where jsonb_gin
    select_where_time = select_from_data(Session, field_name="select_test", field_value=5, mode="jsonb")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="select", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb_gin", exec_time=select_where_time)

    # summarize jsonb_gin data
    summarize_data_time = summarize_data_field(Session, field_name="зарегистрировано всего", mode="jsonb")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="summarize", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb_gin", exec_time=summarize_data_time)

    # delete gin index on jsonb data
    gin_index_delete_time = gin_index_delete(Session, index_name="gin_index")
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="gin_delete", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb_gin", exec_time=gin_index_delete_time)

    # delete jsonb data
    jsonb_delete_time = delete_test(JsonbMedicalData, Session)
    results_dict_insert(results_dict, key="delete", row_number=rows, mode="jsonb", exec_time=jsonb_delete_time)
```

Part of the logs with caching

```
2023-06-21 12:23:18,175 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-21 12:23:18,175 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT sum(CAST(jsonb_medical_data.jsonb_data ->> %(jsonb_data_1)s AS INTEGER)) AS sum_1 
FROM jsonb_medical_data
2023-06-21 12:23:18,175 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 39.2s ago] {'jsonb_data_1': 'зарегистрировано всего'}
2023-06-21 12:23:18,200 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-21 12:23:18,201 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-21 12:23:18,201 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DROP INDEX gin_index
2023-06-21 12:23:18,201 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 37.55s ago] {}
2023-06-21 12:23:18,201 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-06-21 12:23:18,205 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-06-21 12:23:18,205 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DELETE FROM jsonb_medical_data
2023-06-21 12:23:18,205 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 37.54s ago] {}
2023-06-21 12:23:18,232 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: The `[Cached since...` messages refer to the caching of _statements_ - converting SQLA query objects into strings - not data. If you really want to disable this feature, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#disabling-or-using-an-alternate-dictionary-to-cache-some-or-all-statements.